# Compare non-English characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a problem when I try compare 'Đ' and 'D' and I need to return true, but Locale English returns false, because 'Đ' cannot be replaced with regex:

`"\\p{Block=CombiningDiacriticalMarks}+"`.

Comment: Can you try `"[\u0110D]"`? (Đ is code point U+0110)

Comment: @TedHopp: no, just `[\u0110]`, it isn't a combination

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - As I understood it, OP wants 'Đ' to match 'D' and _vice versa_. A character class does just that: treats all characters in the class as equivalent for purposes of matching.

Comment: @TedHopp: Ah, ok! I believed that `\u0110D` stand only for `Đ`

Answer (score 3):

The character class `[\u0110D]` will match either a Đ or a D (Đ is code point U+0110).

### Matching Non-English Characters, a Primer

One common example is the word 'über-geek'. How do I match that word whether or not there is an umlaut above the u? Simple: `[\u0252u]ber-geek` will match either 'über-geek' or 'uber-geek'.

Depending on your regular expression engine, there are multiple great ways to match locale-specific characters. Buy a book on your specific implementation to discover its wrinkles. By the way, you can find an excellent resource for Unicode-specific regex information at Regular-Expressions.info's [Unicode page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

**What if I want to match any character?** If you have access to the `\X` character class, it will act as a `.` in a Unicode context. This means that multiple Unicode code points which combine to form one grapheme will register as one 'character' to the engine.

**NOTE:** I'm not trying to 'steal' an answer to this one, and I'll delete mine if Ted Hopp moves his out of the comments. I just wanted to make sure that people looking for non-English regex matches can see that this question did indeed get answered.